# Python3: Cannot change variables of locals() dictionary inside a function

Tags: python, dynamic, local

Seems like when I pass a variable into a function, I can change it in the globals() dict but not in the locals() dict. Is there a reason for this? So this code

```py
def test(a, dim):
    locals()['dim'] = a
    print(locals()['dim'])
    globals()['dim'] = a
    print(globals()['dim'])

dim = 1
test(4,dim)
```

gives me

```
4
1
```

I'd be very curious to hear why it is how it is and whether you know a way to change locals() variables inside a function.

Comment: Did you hope to learn a way to edit `locals()` because this would be useful to you in some application? Given that this approach won't work, feel free to post a new question if you now have an unresolved problem

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, the locals() dictionary cannot be used to modify variables.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals

> The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may
>   not affect the values of local and free variables used by the
>   interpreter.

You can edit the globals() dictionary, but this is considered nonstandard.